# break website out of iframe/uiwebview on iphone twitter client?

Tags: ios, google-chrome, twitter, safari, mobile-safari

when we click on a link to our site, www.tekiki.com, from inside the twitter iphone client (search for tekiki.com on the twitter mobile client), the site appears in a boxed area.

is this an iframe or something we can break out of? we tried iframe-busting code, but it fails. we suspect this is a uiwebview. if true, can we bust out and open the site in safari/chrome via javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you click on a link within the official Twitter iOS app, it opens up a new modal view that contains a `UIWebView`.  There is no way that you can break out of this view and into a different app since Twitter controls the experience.  iOS only supports fast app switching via registered URL schemes such as `fb://1234567890`, not via javascript, etc.

The only way would be if they had an additional button that gave the user the option to open the page in a different app.